# Why can't I add records with values retrieved from text fields to my mongodb database?

Tags: mongodb

This code is supposed to add a new record from the values the user inputted into the provided text fields but it fails to do so. The program will start running, but after adding the values and pressing the "add" button nothing happens.

```
addButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
             @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
             MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb+srv://admin:test2608@cluster0.mfwsdkr.mongodb.net/compia?retryWrites=true&w=majority");
             MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("compia");
             MongoCollection<Document> collection = database.getCollection("Logs");
             Document document = new Document("logID", logID.getText())
                        .append("processName", processName.getText()).append("type", type.getText()).append("text", text.getText()).append("user", text.getText());
             collection.insertOne(document);
             mongoClient.close();
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successful insertion");
            }
            
        });
```

This is the code I wrote. After running, it does not add values into my collection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with the line:

```
Document document = new Document("logID", logID.getText())
                    .append("processName", processName.getText()).append("type", type.getText()).append("text", text.getText()).append("user", text.getText());
```

You use text.getText() twice to set the values for both "text" and "user" fields. This could be causing the issue in a case where the values are not being added to the database as expected.

You can use the appropriate text field for the "user" field.
Try to replace the line like this:

```
Document document = new Document("logID", logID.getText())
                    .append("processName", processName.getText()).append("type", type.getText()).append("text", text.getText()).append("user", user.getText());
```

Is this solution right for you?